# React component props not updating

Tags: reactjs

Hello Im creating a simple React Component with just a label that change its content when a SignalR method is fired. My react component is like this one:

```
var PersonalityStatusApp = React.createClass({

getInitialState: function () {
    return { data: dataInit };
},

componentWillMount(){
    var self = this;
     this.setState({ data:this.props.status});
        Votinghub.on("UpdateStatusLabel", function (data) {
        var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
        self.setState({ data: obj });
    });
},

render: function () {
    return (
        <div className="PersonalityStatusApp">
             <label>{this.props.status}</label>
        </div>
    );
}
```

});

When te component receives a UpdateStatusLabel signalR message it change the State of the component with the value that gets from the signalR message.

The method UpdateStatusLabel gets the correct value.

[image]

This fires the render method, but when I check the properties in the render method I see thnat the values are still the ones from the initial state.

[image]

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason is, you are updating the state variable and printing the `props` value. Initially `state` variable data will have the value of `this.props` and after you get the `signalR` you are updating the `state` by `data: obj`, so print the value of `this.stat.data.status` it will print the updated value.

use this:

```
return (
    <div className="PersonalityStatusApp">
         <label>{this.state.data.status}</label>
    </div>
);
```

**Note:** Initially you need to set the value of `data: this.props`

Full part:

```
var PersonalityStatusApp = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function () {
        return { data: dataInit };
    },

    componentWillMount(){
        var self = this;
        this.setState({ data: this.props});                 //changed this
        Votinghub.on("UpdateStatusLabel", function (data) {
            var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
            self.setState({ data: obj });
        });
    },

    render: function () {
        return (
            <div className="PersonalityStatusApp">
                 <label>{this.state.data.status}</label>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```